# mi base de datos tiene un problema con las bases de datos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

tengo un problema aqui con mi base de datos, estoy creando las tablas y al momento de ejecutarlas las tabla que tienen llave foranea me dan error.

[image: el error]

Comment: Por lo que veo en el error es que ya existe esa foreign key en la base de datos. cuando crees una fk mejor ponle el nombre de la tabla origen y la de destino para que no tengas problemas de duplicidad `fk_profesores_consejo`

Comment: El código en formato código, para que podamos reproducir tu problema de manera rápida, ya que solo tenemos que copiarlo y pegarlo, como imagen, tenemos que escribirlo manualmente